# org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Invalid argument

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to this site and I would like to request your help and expert opinion on this issue.

I'm currently trying to run a simple code using Netbeans and Selenium, but everytime I run the code I get the error **"Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir"**

This is the code I'm trying to run, something weird is that I can successfully run the same code on a different computer.

```
package selenium.test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SeleniumTest {

private static WebDriver driver = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Documents\\Selenium\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");

driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get ("https:\\www.google.com");
}
}
```

Chrome Version: 77.0.3865.90

ChromeDriver Version: 77.0.3865.40

Netbeans: 8.2

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Does the error tell you which line causes this exception?

Comment: @SpartaSixZero - unfortunately no, I'm not really sure what is causing the exception, as I mentioned it's really strange that the same code runs just great on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

Use ChromeOptions. You can specify a directory that's not your user's directory:

```
    ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
    co.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Some\\valid\\data dir\\");
```